# Appium + Java + Android + iOS : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, mobile-automation

**Question:**

How to fix : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Vmethods.

More info:

I observed this error for android as well as iOS platform.

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**:  com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:245)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)

Any one resolved this? If anyone is also facing same issue, please add your findings in comments.

**Environment:**

- Mac iOS Version : 10.12 [macOS Sierra]
- Appium : Appium1.8.1
- Xcode : 9.3

Comment: Can you specify the version numbers that worked for you, i am also facing same error and currently using java-client 6.1.0 . and selenium-java 3.12.0

Comment: Moved to other project but I do remember we used older java-client  than version 6.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

1. Verify version is appropriate for "guava"
2. If not Update version from link "[guava_versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.0)"
3. For me it started working again when updated below version under POM.XML

   - guava
   - selenium-android-driver
   - android
   - selenium-remote-driver

Answer (score 0):

I just started to work on Appium From scratch. I installed Appium Server Desktop version on Windows (Appium Version 1.22.0)

Then I created Simple Java code to say deploy an app on Android Phone using below code:

```
 public static final String APPIUM_SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";

 DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
 dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
 dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10");
 dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apk);
 dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "FA6C60304130");
 dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
 dc.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

 driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(APPIUM_SERVER_URL), dc);
```

I am using 7.5.1 version of Java client:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Not sure, why it is throwing below exception. In the past I used similar code to run my test. Only thing which was changed was Appium Server version and java-client version for Appium. Previously I used 4.1.2 version of java client and not sure which version of server.

Does anyone know what is the problem and how to get rid of it?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:261)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:338)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:96)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/36028)